# Is there a way to make sed not wait for complete lines?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, sed

`sed` seems to process its input line by line. This is usually not a problem, but if you have really long lines, you can run into issues. For example, the following command never outputs anything:

```
{ while :; do echo -n a; done } | sed "s/a/b/"
```

Naively, it seems like it should be possible to output something as soon as a character is received (at least with this pattern). I've tried `sed -u`, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I thought that the explanation was that the output of sed to a TTY is line-buffered, so nothing happens until there is an LF, which will never come. However if I pipe to file, the file never grows (and in that case the buffering is not line-based). Also `top` shows that `sed` is using significant CPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [sed FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq5.html#s5.10):

> Sed works like this: sed reads one line at a time, chops off the terminating newline, puts what is left into the pattern space where the sed script can address or change it...

So `sed` doesn't really look at your data before a newline occurs in the input.

In your simple case, a simple `tr 'a' 'b'` will replace sed efficiently

Otherwise, maybe add LF in the input, and remove them in the `sed` output

Comment: `tr`? No. If it was `s/a/b/g` then yes. With `s/a/b/` – no.

Answer (score 3):

It had to be some special implementation of `sed`. I don't expect such implementation to exist.

Reasoning:

- [POSIX specification of `sed`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) explicitly says "the input files shall be text files". [Text files](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403) consist of lines that "do not contain NUL characters and none can exceed `{LINE_MAX}` bytes in length, including the newline character". `{LINE_MAX}` is greater or equal to `{_POSIX2_LINE_MAX}` and the latter is `2048` ([link](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/basedefs/limits.h.html)). Therefore issues with really long lines are "normal" (compare [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/552706/108618)).
- `sed` does not take patterns, it takes scripts. It reads a line to the pattern space before executing the script, executes, then prints the (altered) pattern space and reads the next line.

  In your case it's not "it should be possible at least with this pattern" but "at least with this script". The tool should analyze the entire script and decide if it should (or could) change its line-based behavior. Some simple scripts (like yours) may allow this in theory. A pattern like yours may work, but even for little more complicated patterns problems occur. Example:

  In `s/a.*b/c/` the `.*` snippet is greedy. The input stream is not limited in its length. How to find the last `b`?

  My point is the change of behavior could safely be done for few simple scripts, few simple patterns. If more complex scripts/patterns qualify in theory and you'd like to take advantage of this fact, then the analyzing logic would have to be more complex. And if the input turned out to be textual in terms of POSIX (note `sed` doesn't know this in advance) then this "optimization" wouldn't matter.

  If `sed` supported what you want, it would need to do extra work each time; and the extra code responsible for the alternative behavior would need to be maintained. All this to cover few rare needs. A solution would be an option that would allow this extra functionality in an opt-in fashion.

---

There is a tool that can do what you want, at least when the script is simple enough. It's [`bbe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4999140/10765659) (`bbe` package in Debian). If your search and replace in sed was global (`s/a/b/g`) then you could proceed like this:

```
{ while :; do echo -n a; done } | bbe -e 's/a/b/'
# output may not appear immediately, but it will
```

My tests show that this tool always treats `s/foo/bar/` as global.

To circumvent this you need to specify what blocks of data to process (see `man 1 bbe`). The following variant will process a block from the beginning of the input stream to the first occurrence of `a` (remaining bytes will go through unaltered; if no such block is found, the entire stream will go through unaltered):

```
bbe -b '0:/a/' -e 's/a/b/'
```

This way at most one `a` will be replaced by `b` in the *entire* stream.

It gets tricky when you need `bbe` to replace only the first `a` in each line, i.e. emulate sed's `s/a/b/`, possibly with very long lines or when the last line is never terminated. The trick is to define blocks that start with newline character and end with `a`. Anything that is not inside any block will not be altered. This command:

```
bbe -b '/\n/:/a/' -e 's/a/b/'
```

will replace only the first `a` in each line but the first line (because the first line has no newline character before it, it cannot belong to a block). To deal with this you need to prepend an extra newline, which you will remove later.

Example processing of multi-line input with "neverending" last line:

```
{ echo     # extra newline, it will be removed by tail later
  echo "Actual input starts with capital A."
  echo "Note there are multiple 'a' characters in this line."
  # "neverending" line generator below
  while :; do echo -n a; done
} | bbe -b '/\n/:/a/' -e 's/a/b/' | tail -c +2
# output may not appear immediately, but it will
```

Output:

```
Actubl input starts with capital A.
Note there bre multiple 'a' characters in this line.
baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa…
```

Notes:

- `bbe` support for regular expressions seems nonexistent(?).
- `bbe` works with bytes, `sed` works with characters (multi-byte characters in general).

Comment: "*It had to be some special implementation of sed. I don't expect such implementation to exist.*". Just GNU sed. As stated in the FAQ, unlike other versions, it has an unlimited input buffer.

Comment: @xenoid Yet GNU sed doesn't work for the OP, does it? So it's far from implementation I'm talking about. Unlimited input buffer is not enough.